# Can't get transports in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

When I run `$.connection.hub.start()` I get these errors from "resources" (I traced it).

**These are the errors i'm getting**

```
errorOnNegotiate -> "Error during negotiation request.".
errorParsingNegotiateResponse -> "Error parsing negotiate response.".
errorSourceError -> "Error raised by EventSource".
eventSourceFailedToConnect -> "EventSource failed to connect.".
longPollFailed -> "Long polling request failed.".
noConnectionTransport -> "Connection is in an invalid state, there is
no transport active.". nojQuery -> "jQuery was not found. Please
ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR client JavaScript
file.". noTransportOnInit -> "No transport could be initialized
successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for
auto initialization.".
```

Comment: "jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR client JavaScript file."

Answer (score 0):

Part of the error is this : "jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR client JavaScript file.""

you need to add jQuery reference this can be done like so (Please note that in this sample the signalR version is 2.0.2 you need to add the correct reference to the version you are using):

```
 <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
 <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.7.2.js

Do you know which HIGHER version of jquery can be used?

Comment: I've used 1.7.x and 1.8.x and 1.10.x

Comment: I used bundle to load jquery



<script src="~/SignalR/hubs"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start();      
    }())
</script>

Comment: TO add the code to your question , go to your question and press the edit butto

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've pasted the contents of the resources object within signalR._.error().  That object contains a list of possible errors, not the error your're getting.  For example, here it's being used to get the error message when the negotiation response couldn't be parsed:

```js
try {
                        res = connection._parseResponse(result);
                    } catch (error) {
                        onFailed(signalR._.error(resources.errorParsingNegotiateResponse, error), connection);
                        return;
                    }
```

To see which error you're actually getting, look at what the code is trying to utilize from this object.